# Is it possible to change the height of a QProgressBar?

Tags: python, pyside2

I'm trying to change the height of the inner bar.

- I already tried to change the height of the chunk, but the hole bar just vanished.
- I also tried to change the chunks padding, but nothing happend.

```py
from PySide2 import QtWidgets

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setStyleSheet("""
                           QProgressBar {
                               background-color: #C0C6CA;
                               border: 0px;
                               padding-top: 11px;
                               padding-bottom: 10px;
                           }
                           QProgressBar::chunk {
                               background: #7D94B0;
                           }
        """)
        self.progress_bar()

    def progress_bar(self):
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        progress = QtWidgets.QProgressBar()
        progress.setTextVisible(False)
        progress.setValue(35)
        layout.addWidget(progress)
        self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I want a chunk with the same height of the progressbar itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `::chunk` subcontrol is used to change the chunk progress (i.e. the rectangles in the progress bar).

If you want to have a progress bar with the same size of its background, remove the padding:

```
self.setStyleSheet("""
QProgressBar {
 background-color: #C0C6CA;
 border: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 // height: 100px; // To change the progress bar height
}
QProgressBar::chunk {
 background: #7D94B0;
 width:5px
}
""")
```

It will display:

[image]

Comment: I needed to use `max-height` instead of `height`.